# ng-repeat with simple nested array not acting as expected

Tags: angularjs

Why does this `ng-repeat`

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="rows in pics">
    <a class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="pic in rows" data-lightbox="DCS_{{pic}}" href="./large/DCS_{{pic}}.jpg">
        <img src="./previews/DCS_{{pic}}.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

with this controller

```
app.controller('galleryController', ['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.pics = [
    [8146],
    [8147],
    [8230],
    [8234]
],[
    [8253],
    [8295],
    [8311],
    [8344]
];
}]);
```

produce markup like this?

```
<div class="row ng-scope" ng-repeat="rows in pics">
    <!-- ngRepeat: pic in rows --><a class="col-md-3 ng-scope" ng-repeat="pic in rows" data-lightbox="DCS_8146" href="./large/DCS_8146.jpg">
        <img src="./previews/DCS_8146.jpg">
    </a><!-- end ngRepeat: pic in rows -->
</div>
<div class="row ng-scope" ng-repeat="rows in pics">
    <!-- ngRepeat: pic in rows --><a class="col-md-3 ng-scope" ng-repeat="pic in rows" data-lightbox="DCS_8147" href="./large/DCS_8147.jpg">
        <img src="./previews/DCS_8147.jpg">
    </a><!-- end ngRepeat: pic in rows -->
</div>
```

i.e. repeating `<div class='row'>` for every single item in the inner arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `$scope.pics` should be defined in a bit different way:

```
$scope.pics = [
   [8146, 8147, 8230, 8234],
   [8253, 8295, 8311, 8344]
];
```

In other words, that should be a two-dimensional array: elements of the outer array correspond to rows, and its elements (inner arrays) are images data.

With the code in your question, you actually store just a single row in that variable - all the other rows are basically ignored. Compare your code with this:

```
$a = [ [1], [2], [3] ], [ [4], [5], [6] ];
JSON.stringify($a); // "[[1],[2],[3]]"
```

See, `comma` operator precedence is lower than `=` one. So that expression is processed as...

```
($a = [ [1], [2], [3] ]),
 [ [4], [5], [6] ];
```

... that is, assignment operation is done for the first 'row' only.

Comment: Ah, of course. I put every number into an array, what was I thinking? Sorry, brain fart lol.